# Trigger reading from two view tables and write on a different table takes more than 12 seconds, what might be the issue here?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, trigger, view, ddl-trigger

Trigger reading from two view tables and write on a different table takes more than 12 seconds, what might be the issue here?

In my case, I am using a trigger to read from two view tables (Decisions2 and Con_Decisions_Groupby), each table contains more than 20000 records, and only I want the trigger to work with the updated values and if a new record is added to the view table, and not to go through all the records in order to hide the delay.
This is my trigger: (I am not sure if it is written correctly to cover my case)

```
USE [W1]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [azteca].[trg_WOcommittee_02]    Script Date: 6/5/2018 10:23:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [azteca].[trg_WOcommittee_02]
   ON [azteca].[WORKORDER]
   AFTER UPDATE, insert
AS 
   UPDATE [azteca].[REQUEST] 

SET [azteca].[REQUEST].[TEXT11] = [dbo].[Decisions2].[L1_Desecion], 
    [azteca].[REQUEST].[TEXT12] = [dbo].[Decisions2].[L2_Desecion],
    [azteca].[REQUEST].[TEXT13] = [dbo].[Decisions2].[R1_Desecion],
    [azteca].[REQUEST].[TEXT14] = [dbo].[Decisions2].[R2_Desecion],
     [azteca].[REQUEST].[TEXT4] = [dbo].[Decisions2].[HPC1_Desecion],
    [azteca].[REQUEST].[TEXT15] = [dbo].[Decisions2].[SPC2_Desecion], 
    [azteca].[REQUEST].[TEXT5] = [dbo].[Decisions2].[Drafting],
    [azteca].[REQUEST].[TEXT2] = [dbo].[Decisions2].[Auditing_Desecion],

        [azteca].[REQUEST].[TEXT20]= [dbo].[Con_Decisions_Groupby].[TEXT20]


FROM [azteca].[REQUEST]  FULL JOIN [dbo].[Decisions2] ON [azteca].[REQUEST].[REQUESTID] = [dbo].[Decisions2].[REQUESTID] 
                       Full join [dbo].[Con_Decisions_Groupby] on [azteca].[REQUEST].REQUESTID =  [dbo].[Con_Decisions_Groupby].REQUESTID
```

Kindly find the attached screen shot which shows all the story:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read the accpted answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and also [this](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) and [this](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql). Take the tour and visit the help desk to see what's on- and off-topic for this site - you're OK on this score, your question is on-topic! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: You'll need to join to the `inserted` table to limit updates to the affected rows. There is no mention of the `azteca.WORKORDER` table in your trigger code so I'm guessing table is used in the views. You should add the `CREATE VIEW` DDL to your question. The `FULL JOIN`s with no `WHERE` clause look odd and the screen shots don't tell any story I understand.

Comment: Thank you Dan, really appreciate your answer, the view table is reading from the azteca.workorder table and when adding the trigger to the view table, the trigger is not working, Sorry for the confusion, [lease find the code of  the view tables:

Comment: "You'll need to join to the inserted table to limit updates to the affected rows" - @DanGuzman

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion, the view table is reading from the azteca.workorder table and when adding the trigger to the view table, the trigger is not working,  please find the code of  the view tables:
[dbo].[Decisions2]>>>

```
SELECT        REQUESTID, Communities, ObjID, [L1] AS [L1_Desecion], [L2] AS [L2_Desecion], [R1] AS [R1_Desecion], [R2] AS [R2_Desecion], [HPC1] AS [HPC1_Desecion], [HPC2] AS [SPC2_Desecion], [Drafting] AS [Drafting], 
                     [Auditing] AS [Auditing_Desecion], Attachments, PROBLEMSID
```

FROM            (SELECT        TEXT1, REQUESTID, Communities, ObjID, Attachments, COMMENTS, PROBLEMSID
                          FROM            dbo.RequestToWorkorder) src PIVOT (max(TEXT1) FOR COMMENTS IN ([L1], [L2], [R1], [R2], [HPC1], [HPC2], [Drafting], [Auditing])) piv;

[dbo].[Con_Decisions_Groupby]>>>

```
SELECT        MAX(REQUESTID) AS REQUESTID, TEXT20
```

FROM            dbo.Con_Decisions
GROUP BY REQUESTID, TEXT20